# Custom titlepage

Tags: titles

I'm trying to achieve that layout for this title page : [image: title page]  and I'm a bit lost where to start. The layout is pretty straight forward but how to write in LaTeX is cumbersome to me. On the picture only position and colors matters.

Give me hints to do it, I really would like to do it myself. I'm trying to build a class if it can interfere with the syntax.

Comment: In general have a look at the titlepage package, maybe this guide helps you: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: Maybe a `biever` can give you a hint as well.

Comment: Have a look at the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291594/9632). You will obviously be able to create your custom title page using for example [textpos](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will have look to these packages as well !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`textpos` package allows one to position elements on a page.  The size of the page can be defined with the `geometry` package.  See the LaTeX font catalogue for your preferred font.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{PetrolBlue}{RGB}{1,95,147}
\definecolor{CloudBlue}{RGB}{178,206,230}
\definecolor{SteelBlue}{RGB}{36,130,192}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext,eulerpx}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{textblock*}{.5\paperwidth}(.5\paperwidth,0cm)
    \textblockcolor{CloudBlue}
    \parindent=3mm% this is used to set the width of the vertical blue band (3mm in this case)
    {\color{PetrolBlue}\vrule height \paperheight width \dimexpr.5\paperwidth-\parindent\relax}
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0cm,.4\paperwidth)
    \textblockcolor{SteelBlue}\vskip2mm
    \centering
    \color{white}\fontsize{2.1cm}{2.5cm}\selectfont Title\par\vskip2mm
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{.3\paperwidth}(.5cm,.5cm)
    \parindent=0mm%
    \includegraphics[width=.3\paperwidth,height=.35\paperwidth]{example-image}
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{.12\paperwidth}(.35\paperwidth,.6\paperheight)
    \parindent=0mm%
    \textblockcolor{white}
    \includegraphics[width=.12\paperwidth,height=.15\paperwidth]{example-image}\par\bigskip
    \includegraphics[width=.12\paperwidth,height=.15\paperwidth]{example-image}\par\bigskip
    \includegraphics[width=.12\paperwidth,height=.15\paperwidth]{example-image}
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{.4\paperwidth}(.6\paperwidth,1cm)
    \textblockcolor{PetrolBlue}
    \raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{1cm}{1.2cm}\selectfont 
    Date\qquad\null
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{.4\paperwidth}(.6\paperwidth,.6\paperheight)
    \textblockcolor{PetrolBlue}
    \color{white}\fontsize{1cm}{1.2cm}\selectfont 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
      Author 1\\ 
      Author 2
    \end{tabular}
  \end{textblock*}
  \begin{textblock*}{.4\paperwidth}(.6\paperwidth,.8\paperheight)
    \parindent=0mm%
    \textblockcolor{PetrolBlue}
    \color{white}\fontsize{1.2cm}{1.4cm}\selectfont Some\\ Text here
  \end{textblock*}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's exactly that : I'm not looking at your answer and I might post my own if I succeed. Thanks a lot !