# OR Spectrum latex template

Tags: templates

I'm trying to achieve that layout for this title page :
https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/or-spectrum-springer-latex-template/fvthmyrnygjm
The layout is pretty straight forward but how to write in LaTeX is cumbersome to me. Give me hints to do it, I really would like to do it myself. I'm trying to build a class if it can interfere with the syntax.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291594/help-needed-to-create-a-relatively-complex-page-for-the-cover-of-a-textbook

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244399/are-there-any-packages-providing-collections-of-title-pages